button click is delayed
So I made a game where the buttons have certain texts and there is a main_button which displays all the texts from a list repeatedly by using recursive method, I had made two functions one : onclick() which configs text on all buttons and another speed_text() which displays the text to the main_button repeatedly
now the thing is these two functions are irrelated to each other but when function two is happening (displaying text on main_button) then I press the other buttons so to match text and display 'win' but the click of button is always getting delayed, I think it is because of recursion on the first function to repeatedly show the text from list
So I need your help to explain the things and help me to improve the code and remove delay of buttons.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import random
import time     

def speed_text():
    
    speed_text_list = ['a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','0','6','9']
    current_event = random.choice(speed_text_list)
    main_button.config(text = current_event)
    window.update()
    time.sleep(3)
    speed_text()                 # here is what I think is source of error

def event_text():

    global list_with_items
    button_event = random.choice(list_with_items)
    list_with_items.remove(button_event)
    return button_event

def onclick(row, column):
    
    global tries
    tries += 1
    tries_label.config(text = 'tries : {}'.format(tries))
    if buttons[row][column]['text'] == main_button['text']:
        buttons[row][column].config(bg = 'green')
        main_button.config(bg = 'green')
        window.update()
        main_button.destroy()
        window.update()
    else:
        pass

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Game')

event_list = ['a','s','d','f',
              'g','h','j','k',
              'l','0','6','9']

list_with_items = event_list

buttons = [[0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0],
           [0,0,0,0]]

current_event = random.choice(event_list)

main_button = Button(window, fg = 'red', font = ('consolas',40), width = 5, height = 2, borderwidth = 5)
main_button.pack(side = 'top', pady = 10)

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

for row in range(3):
    for column in range(4):
        buttons[row][column] = Button(frame, borderwidth = 5, font = ('consolas',20), width = 5, height = 2,
                                      command = lambda row = row, column = column :onclick(row, column),
                                      text = event_text())
        buttons[row][column].grid(row = row, column = column)
tries = 0
tries_label = Label(window, text = 'tries : {}'.format(tries), font = ('consolas',40))
tries_label.pack(side= 'bottom', pady = 20)

speed_text()

window.mainloop()


Instead of window.update(), time.sleep(3), and speed_text(), try using window.after(3000, speed_text). For more info ready this

window.after(300, speed_text) . Comment out #speed_text()
